# htaccess rewrite all subdomains to url path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i need to redirect all request going to any subdomain on domain1.com to domain2.com passing the subdomain part as path, so for example:

sub1.domain1.com -> domain2.com/sub1

this works with my current rewrite rule:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+?\.domain1\.com$ [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

but when i have a subdomain like the following, it doesn't work:

sub1.sub2.domain1.com -> is redirecting to domain2.com/ without taking the subdomain parts to the path. (domain2.com/sub1.sub2)

how can i get this to work for any combination of subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see who *any* such redirection currently works. The rewriting rule you posted certainly does *not* do what you describe...

I suggest such an approach to hand over the "subdomain name":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:(.+)\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain2.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

> https://sub1.sub2.domain1.com/some/path => https://domain2.com/sub1.sub2

This obviously will ignore whatever path has originally been requested, but that is what you intend, as I understood. If you also want to keep the path and only precede it with the subdomain name, then this variant should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:(.+)\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://domain2.com/%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

> https://sub1.sub2.domain1.com/some/path => https://domain2.com/sub1.sub2/some/path

It is a good idea to start out using a 302 redirection and only change that to a 301 once things work as desired. That prevents you from running into caching issues...

Comment: Hi, thank you. But it is still redirecting me to domain2.com/ when i try to go to sub1.sub2.domain1.com. The original path is out of scope, i just need the subdomain(s) part to be in the path after the redirection.

Comment: The first variant will append the "subdomain names" as path. I checked that the pattern matches. So the question is: why doesn't it work in your setup? 1. Check if you are _really_ not looking at cached results (anonymous browser, browser's network console, http server's access log). 2. Check if those rules actually do get applied. How did you make sure that is the case, how did you check that? Also consult your http server's error log file and compare the entries in there, especially make a try impementing a definite error in that configuration file, does _that_ result in error entries?